# Antd design InputNumber flicker issue on trying to change the value

Tags: reactjs, antd

Flickering issue https://ant.design/components/input-number/

1. Use the 2nd Input group of `InputNumbers`
2. Select the `InputNumber` value by double clicking on it and change the value
3. Cursor will flicker in `InputNumber field` and value will not change until we move mouse or use touch pad to focus out

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Everything seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @ChrisB. its firefox and Mac OS

Comment: Ah, I couldn't see the GIF earlier. Yeah, this is definitely an issue with AntD's library. I use it myself and there are certainly still bugs to be worked out. I'd create an issue on their Github page.